# spreadsheet Determining days between two dates when criteria met

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Could not find the answer to this one although it seems not too hard: calculate number of days between day and a day in the next x rows marked as a settlement day (=TRUE)

Please see example sheet for setup:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E8bGpB8_xj1WECHOuP4Q0nH7Cx2FHilWvZ9h3ih0KwE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C4:

```
=INDEX(A4:$A$1004000,MATCH(TRUE,B4:$B$1004000,0))-A4
```

[image]

Note:  It depends on the dates in Column A being true dates and not text that looks like dates.

For Google Sheets the above formula will work but it can be truncated to:

```
=INDEX(A4:$A,MATCH(TRUE,B4:$B,0))-A4
```

Comment: Looks fine to me (have added an upvote). An alternative without `INDEX` or `MATCH` would be `=IF(B3,0,C4+(A4-A3))`, but this is slightly messier if the list doesn't end with a `TRUE` date (or fills the worksheet!).

Comment: @Nick I like that one.  The Index/Match will error also if the last cell is not True.

Comment: @Scott Craner Thank you, that works like a charm! I added the networkdays function since I forgot to mention that I needed working days.

Comment: @user3149095 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.